# Firebase error "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this firebase project" on iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have integrated Firebase into my iOS App and have been using Firebase Authentication successfully for more than a year and The provider is enabled on Firebase console.
 
However, now when trying to verify a user's phone number using the phone authentication method on real device ,when running this code:

[image]

I started receiving the following error :-

**Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17006 "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."**

I've checked my Firebase console and provider is enabled. Any ideas on how to fix it?? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you please show us how did you enable that in the Firebase Console?

Comment: Did you check the sms region policy? It is under settings in the auth path. There you can specify which country codes are allowed to receive a code. If you haven't set that up, you will get that error.

Comment: @IT-Guy007 I tried this but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to not set any **SMS Region Policy**

- Go to Firebase Project
- Authentication
- Settings
- SMS Region Policy